# regular expression - character set in exclusion group

Tags: regex

Trying to write a regex that can split title and author given the syntax:

Author Name - Title

The title can contain multiple "-".

I have the following regex: `([^-]*) - (.*)`

This works for most cases, e.g.

```
Douglas Adams - Life, The Universe & Everything
```

splits into `Douglas Adams` and `Life, The Universe & Everything`

but fails for double barrelled author names - 
e.g. `Ayize Jama-Everett - Some Book Title` as I then get:

Author = `Everett`

So I want to change the exclusion group `[^-]` to exclude the group `" - "`, as hyphens in the name will not have spaces surrounding them.

How do I do this?

Comment: It would help to know what language/library you're doing this with, since some regex features differ.

Comment: It doesn't matter - A working answer in any language will work for me as I can translate once I know the theory

Comment: `[^-]*` will never match any full title with `-`'s in them, like you specified.

Comment: No that one picks up the author - i.e. it works fine unless the author also contains hyphens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you need [lazy quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html):

```
(.*?) - (.*)
```

First group will get minimum number of symbols before `-`. The second will capture the rest. It'll not match if there is no `-` in the string.

Depending of how you're using it. You can also force it match with whole string by adding start and end quantifiers:

```
^(.*?) - (.*)$
```

Comment: No the ? is essential otherwise the first capture group will include sections of the title if the title also contains space-hyphen-space combos as indicated in the question

Answer (score 1):

If you know that " - " is the delimiter between author name and book title just do a simple string split on that delimiter. A regex seems like overkill for this.

In Python:

```
>>> "Author Name-Hyphen - Book Title".split(" - ")
['Author Name-Hyphen', 'Book Title']
```

Answer (score -1):

The "character" class *everything but space-hyphen-space* looks like tbis—which is a good reason not to do it this way (example in Perl):

```perl
say "author=($1) title=($2)"
    if q{foo bar-baz - taz-fraz daz} =~ m/((?: [^-]|(?:[^ ]-[^ ]))+ ) \s - \s (.+)/x
#                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#                                          this mess here
```

That uses the alternation `[^-]` or `[^ ]-[^ ]` (non-space, hyphen, non-space) repeated one or more times. Character classes have to be one character—but alternatives do not.

Instead, you should use "split" (or whatever the equivalent in your language is)

```
my ($author, $title) = split(/ - /, $record, 2);
```

which takes everything up to `-` and puts it in $author, then the rest in title.